# Как округлить до двух знаков после запятой, оставив последний 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, округление

Есть последовательность чисел вида 1/1 , 1/4, 1/7, 1/10 ...
Надо найти её сумму в зависимости от n, где n - количество слагаемых, и округлить эту сумму до двух знаков после запятой, т.е. если результат равен 2, то выводиться должно 2.00.

Но если, например, n = 18, то выводится 2.0 , а не 2.00.

Или если n = 59, то выводится 2.4, а не 2.40.

И таких примеров еще много можно привести, где вторая цифра после запятой ноль. Интересно, что когда ответ равен 2.00 , то первый ноль остается. В чем дело?

Ссылка на задачу: https://www.codewars.com/kata/555eded1ad94b00403000071

```
def series_sum(n):
array = [1, 4]
sum = 0.00
if n >2:
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        number = array[i] + 3
        array.append(number)
for i in array:
    sum += 1/i
if n ==1:
    return "1.00"
if n == 0:
    return "0.00"
answer = round(sum, 2)
return str(answer)
```

Comment: Замените `return str(answer)`  на  `return "{:.2f}".format(answer)`

Comment: ____спасибо!____